# How to conditionally hide PXTabItem inside an Acumatica screen?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I want to HIDE the Sales Order Line Commissions Tab, but I only want the Tab Hidden for a Specific Role. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option #1: Using PXTabItem VisibleExp property

This approach works perfectly with fairly simple declarative conditions, which utilize input control values from a particular container (**PXForm** is most commonly used for this scenario).

For example, to hide the Sales Order Commissions tab for orders of the ***TR*** type, you should compose **VisibleExp** as follows:

```
<px:PXTabItem Text="Commissions"
              VisibleExp="DataControls[&quot;edOrderType&quot;].Value!=TR" 
              BindingContext="form" 
              RepaintOnDemand="false">
```

A quick overview of the 3 **PXTabItem** properties used in the code snippet above:

- **BindingContext**: the ID of the container control hosting input controls used to calculate visible property for PXTabItem
- **VisibleExp**: the expression to calculate visible property for PXTabItem
- **RepaintOnDemand**: controls the initialization of PXTab control. When set to True (the default value) PXTabItem will be initialized only when a user selects the Tab, otherwise, it will initialize with every postback.

#### Option #2: In code hide all controls placed inside PXTabItem

Without a doubt, this approach is a step forward in terms of flexibility comparing to **PXTabItem VisibleExp** property. It allows you to compose way more complex conditions inside business logic and do not rely on a webpage.

To hide the Sales Order Commissions tab, you should subscribe to the RowSelected handler for SOOrder as follows:

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        SOOrder order = (SOOrder)e.Row;
        if (order == null) return;

        bool financeRoleMember = System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole("FINANCE");
        Base.SalesPerTran.AllowSelect = financeRoleMember;
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<SOOrder.salesPersonID>(Base.Document.Cache, null, financeRoleMember);
    }
}
```

With **AllowSelect** property set to false, the **SalesPerTran** data view will automatically hide every **PXGrid**, whose **DataMember** property is set to ***SalesPerTran***. Since the Sales Order Commissions tab also contains Default Salesperson lookup, we need to additionally set **Visible** property to ***false*** for the **PXUIFieldAttribute** decorating SOOrder SalesPersonID field. **PXTabItem** automatically hides when it contains no visible controls.

Please be advised, similar to **PXTabItem VisibleExp** property, in order for this approach to function properly, you have to always set **RepaintOnDemand** to ***false*** for the **PXTabItem** you conditionally hide. For this particular example, we can skip this step, because **RepaintOnDemand** is set to ***false*** in the original **SO301000.aspx** file distributed by Acumatica.