# How can you change current tab programmatically with Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

When I launch a custom Framework page, i would to be able to activate one of the tabs programmatically depending on certain conditions. Am i stuck using javaScript or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few posts already on this question with answers:

This is the best answer:  [How to conditionally hide PXTabItem inside an Acumatica screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352576/how-to-conditionally-hide-pxtabitem-inside-an-acumatica-screen)

Also, searching [hide tab](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bacumatica%5D%20hide%20tab) you will find what you need.

Comment: Thanks, thats good info, however, i still want the tab to be present/visible. Are you able to dynamically change the order of the tabs (ie make the one i want the default one)?

Comment: The tab should only be visible if it contains controls that are visible. Otherwise you will have a tab, but it will be completely empty. As for changing the tab order I don't know that that is possible, but I have not tried.

Comment: The question is not how to show/hide, but how to change current tab, that's a bit different

Comment: ah sorry i see now you want to have something auto focus on a tab that is not the first tab. This would be good to know once someone has an answer

Answer (score 0):

For information, this can be achieved statically with PXTab control `SelectedIndex` property:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing and haven't been able to get it to work programmatically. In the code behind I set the SelectedIndex to a different number and the tab doesn't change. Is there some kind of refresh or repaint that can be called or some other way to change the SelectedIndex from code?

Comment: Not that I know, maybe using JavaScript to programmatically click on the tab header once the DOM is loaded could work. For a simple use case, the workaround I suggested is to create multiple static pages (copy) and have each of them open a different tab by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a Javascript function and attaching it to the corresponding client event on your Acumatica form.

Here, I wanted the tab to change based on the index of the active cell in a grid.  So I set the `aftercellchange` and `cellclick`  grid-events(client events) to my `gridclick` Javascript function. Finally, added this script to my aspx page:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function gridClick()
    {
            var index = px_alls["grid"].activeCell.getIndex();
            if(index<=2) px_alls["tab"].items[0].select();
            if(index>=3 && index<=5) px_alls["tab"].items[1].select();
            if(index>=6) px_alls["tab"].items[2].select();
    }
</script>
```