# Focusing Tab in opportunity screen

Tags: acumatica

How do I change default tab focus to Detail tab in Opportunity screen.

[image]

Comment: The question I have asked is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414213/how-can-you-change-current-tab-programmatically-with-acumatica and I want to default the tab to detail Tab in opportunity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set the tab position in the **SelectedIndex** property of the Tab control

[image]