# Acumatica - VisibleExp Multiple Conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I need to show/hide tab for the specific values in a form, I need to use VisibleExp and not PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible.

Let's take a look at an example:

```
VisibleExp="DataControls[&quot;edProductType&quot;].Value == LN"
```

What if I need to compare ProductType to "TR" as well? How can I add "or" or "and" statements in the expression?

Comment: AllowSelect is what you would use for controlling the visibility for a tab assuming all controls are linked to the same data view. I have not tried multiple conditions in the VisibleExp as setting the AllowSelect in the graph is easier to maintain. See this article for more details if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352576/how-to-conditionally-hide-pxtabitem-inside-an-acumatica-screen/46352577#46352577

Comment: Thing is, I have to use VisibleExp with AllowSelect because there are some common fields for 2 tabs and I have to hide one tab when another one is shown. I've solved this problem by using the unbound hidden field. I pass the whole expression value to that field and then I use it for the VisibleExp. It's a kind of weird solution but in fact, it works! Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sounds good. I was thinking of suggesting an unbound field to process your condition. Glad it worked. Would be good to post it as your answer to your own question.

Comment: Could you please check [this KB article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352576/how-to-conditionally-hide-pxtabitem-inside-an-acumatica-screen/) for 2 approaches to conditionally hide PXTabItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by using the unbound hidden field. I pass the whole expression value to that field and then I use it for the VisibleExp. It's a kind of weird solution but in fact, it works!